# How to shard the Django User model/table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, sharding

How do you shard the Django `User` model so that user records will be located in different databases/tables?

Which modules and models and views need to be modified? Do I need to create a custom authentication backend? Is there a relatively painless way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its reasonably difficult due to how Django has been designed unfortunately.

I guess you are concerned with the number of entities one database could hold? Otherwise if thinking of scaling, use normal load balancers - web servers - connection pooling - database cluster setup.